# JFrog Artifactory AQL - Pagination mechanism

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I am currently trying to query **Artifactory** for 25 results.
So I used:

```
items.find({"name" : {"$match":"somefile*"}).limit(25)
```

But I need to get also the Total result for calculate **Total results**.
If there is 500 results, i want to get it also.
For Example:

> 500/25 = 20 pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) command of the JFrog CLI, with the `--count` option to only get the number of results.

Or, using AQL through the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)), you can first query without limit to get the total number of results, by looking at the total count at the range field:

```
{
    "results" : [
    {
        "repo" : "libs-release-local",
        "path" : "org/jfrog/artifactory",
        "name" : "artifactory.war",
        "type" : "item type",
        "size" : "75500000",
        "created" : "2015-01-01T10:10;10",
        "created_by" : "Jfrog",
        "modified" : "2015-01-01T10:10;10",
        "modified_by" : "Jfrog",
        "updated" : "2015-01-01T10:10;10"
    }
    ],
    "range" : {
    "start_pos" : 0,
    "end_pos" : 1,
    "total" : 1 // <----
    }
}
```

Comment: @maoryadin you can do this with REST API, I updated my answer

Comment: but the total, only return the total result that i got.
not the total result that are availiable.
if there is 500 results, and i limit to 25.
i want to get all 25 results, but total of 500.

Comment: To your question about using code to do this, you can look at github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go. This is the golang library used by JFrog CLI.